# Is it possible to create an 'else' based on the result of two (or more) previous 'if's?

Tags: java

Currently I have some code in the `if (roobaf)` block which depends on `foo` and `bar` being false. I can check these conditions again within the block but it feels like unnecessary repetition of code.

```
if (foo) {
    // some code
}

/*else*/ if (bar) {   // bar is a condition which needs to be checked 
                      // whether 'foo' is true or false
// more code
}

if (roobaf) { 

   if (!foo && !bar) {
      // even more code
    }

}
```

The problem is that if `bar` is just an `if`, then `roobaf` will be reached even if foo is true.

If I change `bar` to an `else if` then if `foo` is true then `bar` will not be checked.

How do I make sure that `foo` and `bar` are always checked but that `roobaf` will only be checked if both `foo` and `bar` are checked?

`roobaf` is a condition which is not mutually exclusive with `foo` and `bar` so putting it first will not work.

Comment: Does checked mean true?

Comment: Why not `if (roobaf && !foo && !bar)`?

Comment: @RobOhRob when I say 'checked' I just mean that the condition needs to be evaluated. If either (or both) of 'foo' and 'bar' are true then their code needs to be run, but not `roobaf`

Comment: are they excluding? I mean, foo executes if true, bar executes if true, and roobaf executes if all true?

Comment: @Nexevis yes in my example I could have simplified it that way, but that still leaves me not wanting to not have to test the `foo` and `bar` conditions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
if (foo || bar) {
    if (foo) {
        // do something
    }
    if (bar) {
        // do something
    }
}
else {
    if (roobaf) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Still a little repetitive but it will make my code a lot neater.

Answer (score 1):

nLee's solution is probably the best way to do it I can see, but you seem hung up on not wanting to type `foo` or `bar` again, so you can always set the condition to false inside of the bodies as an alternate.

**Note:** I personally do not think this is a good way to do it to just make the `if` statements less nested.

```
roobaf = true; //Initial Condition
if (foo){
    //Other code
    roobaf = false;
}
if (bar){
    //Other code
    roobaf = false;
}
if (roobaf) {
   //Other code
}
```

Comment: It wasn't a dealbreaker to avoid it, it just seemed unnecessary. I did think about doing it as suggested in your example but, as you say, thought it probably wasn't a good way to do it.